# How do I i adjust both timers using Chrome DevTools in order to complete the segments faster?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, devtools, jquery-countdown

I have been struggling finding the exact values that would allow me to bypass the timer in order to complete sections at a faster rate. Ive tried changing my system time but it only affects one of the timers on the page not that one on the left of the page which is the one that holds more importance. If someone can please show me the way you'd be a life saver quite literally.

https://imgur.com/a/7AyKZFZ

my knowledge is very limited i've took a web developing class in high school back in 2011 PLEASE HELP